# com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:

Tags: jmeter, jms

I tried pushing object message in solace queue using JMeter JMS Publisher. But I am getting below error.
Kindly help on this
Configuration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWQQJ.png)

**Error:**
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not + (position: START_DOCUMENT seen  +... @1:2)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there is an issue with your data file as it cannot be converted into well-formed XML, consider double-checking the way you're generating it or contact the person who provided it to you.

You can also [increase JMeter log verbosity level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) to get more details regarding what's going on by adding the following line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change.

Also be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 4.0 (or whatever version is available on the [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: I am using .csv file, which contain "Hello" word.   Is there any specific format of file for JMS Publisher?

Comment: Then use "Text Message" as "Object Message" means a serializable object in the Java programming language which inherits from [Message](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html) and implements [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface. Also be aware that XML is the standard format for MQ communications so maybe "Hello world" is not the best candidate. Check out [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) for more hints

Comment: Actually i new with Jmeter JMS Publisher. My requirement is that i have to send a message(say for Ex- Hello) in solace queue in object format. so what additional configuration in JMS Publisher i have to do achieve this ?